# Can't map a List of items (Objects reference) in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Im having a problem with a map loop, i can't map my list of items
maybe this is because is a list of references? is there any solution changing the shape of do that?

My code :

```
NavigationRoute initialRoute = NavigationRoute(
  route: '/',
  widget: Home(),
);

NavigationRoute home = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Home',
  route: '/home',
  icon: Icons.home,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: Home(),
);

NavigationRoute cardsNavigator = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Cards',
  route: '/cardsNavigator',
  icon: Icons.card_giftcard,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: CardsNavigator(),
);

NavigationRoute example = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Example',
  route: '/example',
  icon: Icons.business,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: ExamplePage(),
);

List<NavigationRoute> navigation = <NavigationRoute>[
  initialRoute,
  home,
  cardsNavigator,
  example,
];
```

and im trying to use that in the map of items :

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: currentIndex,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                currentIndex = index;
                digitalBankingNavigator.currentState?.pushNamed(
                    digitalBankingRoutes.navigation[currentIndex].route);
              });
            },
            items: digitalBankingRoutes.navigation
                .map((route) => BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(route.icon),
                    label: route.title,
                    backgroundColor: route.color))
                .toList(),
          ),
```

Comment: can you share display error?

Comment: @MiguelEscobarCalderon There is no error shown, i think this is because that is a list of references (Because when i debugged, i couldn't access to the objects)

Answer (score 0):

In `initialRoute` the `title` is `null` but the `label` field in `BottomNavigationBarItem` can not be `null`.

So, you have to give some title in the `initialRoute`.

```
NavigationRoute initialRoute = NavigationRoute(
  // Provided a title here
  title: 'Some Title'
  route: '/',
  widget: Home(),
);

NavigationRoute home = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Home',
  route: '/home',
  icon: Icons.home,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: Home(),
);

NavigationRoute cardsNavigator = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Cards',
  route: '/cardsNavigator',
  icon: Icons.card_giftcard,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: CardsNavigator(),
);

NavigationRoute example = NavigationRoute(
  title: 'Example',
  route: '/example',
  icon: Icons.business,
  color: Colors.teal,
  widget: ExamplePage(),
);

List<NavigationRoute> navigation = <NavigationRoute>[
  initialRoute,
  home,
  cardsNavigator,
  example,
];
```

If you have any doubt comment it.

Comment: Hello! thanks for comment, that was not the error, i tried that before post the issue. Anyway, i decided to change my variables structure to sometime with what i can access from another pages and list with map in every nav where that needed.